# How to select a neighboring html element with xpath?

Tags: xpath

I have a html source in which several input boxes are defined as follows:

```
<div class="jupyter-widgets widget-hbox widget-text" style="">
    <div class="widget-label" style="display: block;">Project:</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
</div>
<div class="jupyter-widgets widget-hbox widget-text" style="">
    <div class="widget-label" style="display: block;">Title:</div>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="">
</div>
...
```

How do I select the `input` element associated with the `Project` element?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
//div[contains(text(), "Project")]/following-sibling::input
```

First part `//div[contains(text(), "Project")]` will find the div element which has "Project" in text attribute, then `/following-sibling::input` will find the input type sibling of that div element.

Read more about these xpath functions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256456(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like: `"//input[@type='text'][1]"` or `"(//input[@type='text'])[1]"`. Respectively the number represents the element you are looking for. Hope it helps.

Comment: As a compromise that could work. But I would prefer a name-related selection (where you specify the name of the element, like `Project` or `Title` and not just rely on some order)

Comment: I see what you mean that should be what you need. `.//div[text()='Title']/input[@type='text']`